# NotFOundError : could not find directory C://Users/Admin/Downloads/assignment2/train

Tags: python

I'm Korean and I'm not good at writing in english.
Please understand my poor english.

An error occurs.
"NotFoundError: Could not find directory C://Users/Admin/Downloads/assignment2/train"
how can I solve this problem?

Here is the code that I wrote.

---

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

base_dir = 'C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/assignment2'
train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'test')

batch_size = 32
num_of_train_imgs = 3934
num_of_test_imgs = 1966
img_height = 50
img_width = 50

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  train_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=num_of_train_imgs)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  train_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=num_of_train_imgs)

test_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  test_dir,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=num_of_test_imgs)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file is placed at that directory?

Comment: Make sure directories exist in your computer

Answer (score 1):

This means the directory 'C://Users/Admin/Downloads/assignment2/train' is not existed. So, after you have your directory, make sure it is existed, if not, create one. Here is the solution:

```
base_dir = 'C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/assignment2'

train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
if not os.path.exists(train_dir):
    os.mkdir(train_dir)

test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'test')
if not os.path.exists(test_dir):
    os.mkdir(test_dir)
```